Clear csv file without change it's fileId using Google App Script
Is it possible to clear content on a csv file and write new content from a spreadsheet on the same csv file on Google Drive? I need to keep the csv with the same fileId, so create/delete another csv is not an option (for Tableau to pickup the same file everyday).
I am thinking to use getDataAsString() and setContent() for the write part. But I can't seem to figure out how to just clear content on the csv file without changing it's fileId.
Thanks.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

From File.setContent() documentation:

setContent(content)
Overwrites the content of the file with a given replacement.

In other words, you do not need to clear the file. Just call the setContent() function with the new content you want to put in there.
